# load only content page

Tags: asp.net, .net, master-pages

I want to know that when we use master page + content page then every time we request any page based on a master page then every time that same master page loads with content page.

So is it possible somethig that when we request pages then only content page must be loaded and not the master page if it is same for requested content pages.

It should only be loaded when it is different for a different content page.

Thanks

Comment: you want to call the master page only once???

Comment: ya exactly ..master page load ones and content page load as per requirement

Comment: Then whats the use of adding the master page to the content page. Better just add them once to the page you want to display it.

Answer (score 2):

MasterPages are implemented as a control of the Page.

Asp.net pages load all the controls needed to render the page.

You will **not** be able to avoid loading the MasterPage control totally, if your page uses it.

If your page size is very huge, and want to reduce the size of data you send across to the client, consider using Partial rendering. [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) should get you started.

If loading your pages takes a lot of time, you should look at caching. 
Asp.net has a lot of methods of caching only parts of a page.

Look at [Caching portions of a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx).